# Detect label display, remove class hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, hidden, removeclass

I want to detect if a `label`'s display is none. If it is, then I'll remove the `hidden` class from the label.

How can this be done in jQuery? I'm new with js & jQuery.

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Comment: Did you https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery+check+if+element+is+hidden

Comment: $(function () {
                if($(label).css('display') === 'none'){
                $('.disp-block').removeClass("hidden");
}
});

I've tried this but I don't know if my syntax is correct

Comment: instead of $('.disp-block') use $(label) here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow below code

```
if(!$("label").is(":visible"))
{
  // remove hidden class
  $("label").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

but if you have multiple labels in your code then try below

```
$("label").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(":visible"))
     $(this).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try below code :-

```
if($("#labelID").is(":visible"))
{
  // remove hidden class
  $("#labelID").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/45/

Comment: how will you get this instance here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
if(!$("#your_label_id").is(":visible"))
   $("#remove_class").removeClass("class_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if($("#lblid").css("display")==='none'){
    $("#lblid").removeClass("hidden");//or $("#lblid").css("display","block")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
if($('label').is(':visible'))
{
  // remove hidden class
 $('.disp-block').removeClass('hidden');
}
```